# Can I run custom php on specific pages in wordpress?

Tags: php, code

I'm making a wp site as a new frontend to an in house system that I designed a while back.

I want to be able to run custom php for grabbing different bits and peices of stuff from my database (mysql) and displaying dynamic data etc , but can't seem to do this.

I thought the code snippets plugin may have helped, but whilst that does run custom PHP, its not call-able on a per page basis, but rather runs no matter where I am, which is not suitable.

Any help appriciated.

Comment: Are you using a custom or child theme?

Comment: I'm using a custom theme called 'sydney'... well I say custom... I got it from the theme library :)

Comment: I'd recommend [creating a child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) on top of Sydney as to not mess with the base code, unless you are never going to update the theme.

Comment: Shortcodes and page templates!

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a child or custom theme, I encourage you to look at the Codex's [Template Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/).

The short answer to your question is yes, you can run custom code on any page you'd like.

The longer answer is still yes, but it's a bit more involved in what your end product is going to look like.

I'll paste in [the part about pages](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#single-page) from the aforementioned page:

> The template file used to render a static page (page post-type). Note that unlike other post-types, page is special to WordPress and uses the following path:
>
> - custom template file – The page template assigned to the page. See get_page_templates().
> - page-{slug}.php – If the page slug is recent-news, WordPress will look to use page-recent-news.php.
> - page-{id}.php – If the page ID is 6, WordPress will look to use page-6.php.
> - page.php
> - singular.php
> - index.php

So, you have the ability to create any one of these custom templates, and apply them to your page, running any code you need.

Comment: so say for example I run a bit of code and go fetch a load of stuff from my db and assign it to variables in php, how do i then show that on page?

Comment: Depends on how you want to lay it out, but usually using a [while](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php) or [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop, with [echo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) or [print](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print.php)